# Saving a database to a text file 

Tags: java

i have got a database which lists actors and movies, these essentially come from two different arrays. I now need to save these from the database into a text file. I don't know if anyone can point me in the right direction, i was thinking filewriter or maybe bufferedwriter?

Comment: So you basically want to **export a table from a database to text file**. What is your database provider (like MySQL, Oracle, etc)?

Comment: u could do it by using export command in Databas or Write java program to fetch records from DB and write to file. If you are writing java program better use filewriter

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data readable in a text file, one easy way to do it is to write the data as a CSV (comma-separated values) file. There are a couple of libraries for reading/writing CSV files. I've used [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) before, and it's quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just select the data and dump it to file? SHould be pretty trivial from the command line, no coding required!

```
mysql -u username -p -D databasename -e "select * from actors" > actors.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the *mysqldump* command. Then you can dump as text the whole DB or isolated tables.